# Soft link (ln -s) won't link to executable

Tags: bash, hyperlink, directory

I have a bash script which produces an executable file (APP.exe) in directory home/aaa/zzz/

When I try to create a link to this executable (which has executable permissions) to create a shortcut in directory home/bbb/yyy/ using absolute paths I get a dead link and I'm not quite sure why. I think the issue is that I am defining paths as variables (since it is a generic script and the locations can change). I want to link the .exe to my simulations folder so that when I rebuild the .exe the link can stay constant and the simulations are all together. My current script contains something similar to:

```
PATH_TO_EXE=/home/aaa/zzz
EXE_NAME=APP.exe
LINK_NAME=link_to_APP
PATH_TO_SIMULATIONS=/home/bbb/yyy

cd $PATH_TO_SIMULATIONS
ln -s $PATH_TO_EXE/$EXE_NAME $LINK_NAME
```

I want the link to APP.exe to work and I can get it to work if I just type the commands into the bash terminal, such as:

```
cd /home/bbb/yyy
ln -s /home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe link_to_APP
```

The .exe is already produced by the time the script reaches this point, so that isn't the issue. I'm using a Linux (Ubuntu) terminal which is up-to-date. I'm not very familiar with bash variables but I understand mostly how they work. I don't really want to have to hard-code anything which is why I'm trying to use variables as the paths (which are read in earlier in the script and I know they're correct from echo). I'm probably missing some quotation marks or something but I've tried many combinations and cannot seem to get it to work properly. When I do an ls of the directory the broken link shows up as:

```
link_to_APP -> /home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe
```

Thank you for looking and any help.

## EDIT:

@Samveen I've included this in the script (slightly renamed variables for easier understanding):

```
cd /home/bbb/yyy
CODE_EXE=APP.exe
CODE_PTH=/home/aaa/zzz
EXE=$CODE_PTH/$CODE_EXE
LINK_NAME=CODE
ln -s $EXE $LINK_NAME
echo ln -s $EXE $LINK_NAME
ls -l $EXE $LINK_NAME
```

And the output:

```
ln -s /home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe CODE
ls: cannot access /home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe: No such file or directory
lrwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 62 Jun 19 09:32 CODE -> /home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe
```

This makes me think the variables are not being read properly? Thanks again.

## EDIT:

I got it to work... but I really didn't change anything. I just went through and tried to find the path at which it would stop locating the .exe and it eventually worked. The actual path connection is much more complicated than the one I used in this example. Thanks @SethMMorton for the helpful explanations.

This is the code that worked (which is basically the same as before):

```
cd $sims_PTH    
# Link the exe
EXE=APP.exe
EXE_PTH=$build_PTH/code/src
rm $LINK_name #delete old link
ln -s $EXE_PTH/$EXE $LINK_name #create new symbolic link
```

Comment: If the link says it is pointing to `/home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe`, what makes you think it is broken?  Does it not work?  What happens when you try  to execute `link_to_APP`?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by *using absolute paths I get a dead link*.

Comment: If I run my script it will produce a link that is Black/Red (instead of the normal blue/green) which means that it isn't really finding/making a link. I can't execute it at all.

If I perform the link through the bash terminal it will work as expected (it links link_to_APP -> APP.exe) and will accept input files. Thanks for looking. I really think it's something with not being able to use variables in the paths?

Comment: And by getting a dead link I mean that I am defining absolute (rather than relative links such as setting ../../home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe as the path) and then the link is symbolically made.

Comment: I promise there is nothing wrong with using environment variables when you run `ln`; they are interpreted *before* being sent to `ln`.  Also, a dead link means that what you are pointing to doesn't exist, not that what you are pointing to has an absolute path.

Comment: @burghermeister can you do `echo ln -s $PATH_TO_EXE/$EXE_NAME $LINK_NAME` followed by `ls -l $PATH_TO_EXE/$EXE_NAME $LINK_NAME` in your script, and paste this debug output in the question?

Comment: I can try to get the output soon... I've since deleted it from my script since it was not working and decided to just cp the .exe to the simulations folder (although this takes more time than creating a link since it is a large file and I would like to avoid it).
-Thanks

Comment: `cannot access /home/aaa/zzz/APP.exe: No such file or directory`  Clearly the EXE you were trying to link to doesn't exist.  You get dead links if you try to link to something that doesn't exist. *That* is your issue. The *method* you were using (`ln -s $EXE $LINK_NAME`) is 100% OK.  The shell expands the variables *before* passing to any command.

Comment: The strange thing is that the .exe does exist... if I were to type the exact same commands (without the variable names) into the bash terminal it would create a proper link (which I have done many times)

This is why I am perplexed as to why it does not seem to find the .exe within my script using variables to define the paths. I'm not expert at bash but I know the .exe file is created and located where I am specifying the link. Thanks for explaining how the variables are expanded first, though. I was unsure of that.